# Rotation of top of symmetries

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, torque, gyroscopes

while learning about rotation, I started to wonder what forces will come into play. Lets picture a top with two masses centered at (-1,0,-1) and (1,0,1) with rods connecting the masses directly to the origin which passes through the axis of rotation. In this system, center of mass is at the origin and axis of rotation is also the axis of symmetry thus we could postulate that it will rotation like a normal top. But if we think of forces acting on it while it rotates, the x, y component of centrifugal forces cancel out but not the z-component. For the mass at (-1, 0,-1) the z component points downwards along the direction of gravity, and for mass at (1, 0, 1) it points upwards but is reduced by gravity. Thus would the difference in centrifugal force, cause change in rotational motion from simple rotation about the axis of symmetry?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are putting the fixed point exactly at the midpoint of the two masses.

What is important is not so much the forces themselves, but their "moment" (or "torque") with respect to the fixed point, which depends on the position of the point where the force is applied. In this situation, the moments of the gravity on each mass are indeed not separately zero, but they do **exactly** cancel each other. So the net effect on the rotation is zero.

However consider a top which is spinning around a fixed point **at the bottom**. Then the moments of the gravity forces do not cancel each other by symmetry (unless the axis of rotation is **perfectly** vertical). And this is why if a top is spinning around an axis which is not perfectly vertical, the axis of rotation itself will slowly turn around the vertical. This is precisely the effect of the unbalance of the moments of the gravity on different parts of the top.